# How to categorize in various categories from list in python

Tags: python

I have a data in list  as follows

```
   ['And user clicks on the link "Statement and letter preferences" -> set([0, 2])',
   'And user waits for 10 seconds -> set([0, 2])',
   'Then page is successfully launched -> set([0, 1, 2])',
   '@TestRun -> set([0, 1, 2])',
   'And user set text "#Surname" on textbox name "surname" -> set([0, 1, 2])',
   'And user click on "menu open user preferences" label -> set([0, 2])']
```

In these data I have set([0,2]) , now I want all the satements that occurs in 0,1,2 in different list ? 
how can we do this in python

Expected output is

list_0  i.e which contains all statements  that has 0 in set(0,2)

```
 list_0     
  [And user clicks on the link "Statement and letter preferences
   And user waits for 10 seconds
   Then page is successfully launched
  '@TestRun 
   And user set text "#Surname" on textbox name "surname
   And user click on "menu open user preferences" label]

 list_1
  [ Then page is successfully launched
  '@TestRun 
   And user set text "#Surname" on textbox name "surname]

  list_2
 [And user clicks on the link "Statement and letter preferences
   And user waits for 10 seconds
   Then page is successfully launched
  '@TestRun 
   And user set text "#Surname" on textbox name "surname
   And user click on "menu open user preferences" label]
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear. Is this a list of strings? What is your expected output?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes list of strings/lines/Statements, Expected output have updated as above. can you please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend appending strings to a dictionary of lists. You'll understand why.

First, here's a high level approach to solving this problem -

1. Iterate over each string
2. Split the string into its content and list of IDs
3. For each ID, add the string to the appropriate dict key.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in data:
    x, y = i.split('->')
    for z in  map(int, re.findall('\d+', y)):
        d[z].append(x.strip())  # for performance, move the `strip` call outside the loop
```

```
print(d)
{
    "0": [
        "And user clicks on the link \"Statement and letter preferences\"",
        "And user waits for 10 seconds",
        "Then page is successfully launched",
        "@TestRun",
        "And user set text \"#Surname\" on textbox name \"surname\"",
        "And user click on \"menu open user preferences\" label"
    ],
    "1": [
        "Then page is successfully launched",
        "@TestRun",
        "And user set text \"#Surname\" on textbox name \"surname\""
    ],
    "2": [
        "And user clicks on the link \"Statement and letter preferences\"",
        "And user waits for 10 seconds",
        "Then page is successfully launched",
        "@TestRun",
        "And user set text \"#Surname\" on textbox name \"surname\"",
        "And user click on \"menu open user preferences\" label"
    ]
}
```

You can find all strings related to ID `i` by querying `d[i]`. This is much cleaner than initialising separate lists.

Comment: @ cOLDSPEEd  I Understand why have we appended strings to a dictonary of lists , but then What i want is i Want to check if these string exists in 0 and 2 than .. add it to list 0 and list 2, but these does not give me these result.

Comment: @CyleySimon Did you try running it? It definitely does. If you print `d[0]` and `d[2]`, you'll see.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I tried  but theses gives me empty list, when i print(d) It gives me statement as key and then values again have these statements repeated twice

Comment: @CyleySimon Do you see my answer? I've shown you the output, it certainly works. What are you doing differently? Please take a look and fix it yourself. I can't debug code that I don't have.

Comment: 'And user verify message on screen "Quick, safe and convenient" -> set([0, 1])': ['And user verify message on screen "Quick, safe and convenient"',
              'And user verify message on screen "Quick, safe and convenient"',
              'And user verify message on screen "Quick, safe and convenient"']

Comment: Above is the output I am getting

Comment: @CyleySimon Okay, there was a typo, please see it again.

Comment: @COLDSPPED, I Checked with d[z] earlier but It gaved me the same result  , I will try it again .. thanks for the help

Comment: @CyleySimon What was the trouble initially?

Comment: Hey I really dont know , May be .. Variables where not updated initailly.I just restarted the IDE and it worked